# How to center-align controls within a FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winforms

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` with a `Label`, `CheckBox`, and `DateTimePicker`. Currently all 3 controls seem to align to the top edge of the `FlowLayoutPanel`:

[image]

This is the same for all of my `FlowLayoutPanel`s. Is there a way to have them all aligned vertically centered like this:

[image]

Here's an example of my code:

```
$flowLayoutPanel = [System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    FlowDirection = "LeftToRight"
    WrapContents = $false
    AutoSize = $true
    Anchor = "Left"
}
$label = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{
    Text = "Expiration"
    AutoSize = $true
    TextAlign = "MiddleLeft"
    UseCompatibleTextRendering = $false
}
$checkBox = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox] @{
    AutoSize = $true
}
$dateTimePicker = [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker] @{
    AutoSize = $true
    MaximumSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(125)
    Format = "Short"
}
$flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(@($label, $checkBox, $dateTimePicker))
```

Comment: Add your Controls to a Container (UserControl / Panel etc.), position them as you please then add the Container to the FLP

Comment: Set Anchor of the child controls to Left, or None. Then their middle will be aligned instead of their top. (I tried it first with TableLayoutPanel, and then I noticed it works with FlowLayoutPanel as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Anchor of the child controls to Left, or None.

[image]

```
$flowLayoutPanel = [System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    FlowDirection = "LeftToRight"
    WrapContents = $false
    AutoSize = $true
    AutoSizeMode = [AutoSizeMode]::GrowAndShrink
    Anchor = "Left"
    BackColor = "Silver"
}
$label = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{
    Text = "Expiration"
    AutoSize = $true
    TextAlign = "MiddleLeft"
    UseCompatibleTextRendering = $false
    Anchor = "Left"
}
$checkBox = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox] @{
    AutoSize = $true
    Anchor = "Left"
}
$dateTimePicker = [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker] @{
    AutoSize = $true
    MaximumSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(125)
    Format = "Short"
    Anchor = "Left"
}
$flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(@($label, $checkBox, $dateTimePicker))
```

To learn more about FlowLayoutPanel, you can take a look at:

- [FlowLayoutPanel Control (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Anchor and Dock Child Controls in a FlowLayoutPanel Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).